# sort element by value of alphanumeric data attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to sort my content using this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $wrapper = $('.product-list');

$wrapper.find('.product').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('data-title') - +b.getAttribute('data-title');
})
.appendTo( 'body' );
});
```

but it only works if the `data-title` is a numeric value. I need to be able to use letters & numbers.

Here is Demo of what I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/XKy9Z/

Comment: I've upvoted this useful question to get it back to "0" -- why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort it alphabetically, you can use following snippet:

```
$wrapper.find('.product').sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.getAttribute('data-title') < b.getAttribute('data-title')) ? -1 : (a.getAttribute('data-title') > b.getAttribute('data-title')) ? 1 : 0;
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XKy9Z/2/)

Comment: +1, I prefer [your approach](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XKy9Z/4/) to the [one *I* came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XKy9Z/3/).

Comment: This does exactly what I want, than you very much. I had soo much trouble with this. Thank you for your time also David.